# Grails - excluding class from JSON response works only after hot code loading

Tags: json, grails

I've set up a JSON renderer in `resources.groovy`:

```
...
myModelJsonRenderer(JsonRenderer, MyModel) {
    excludes = ['class']
}
...
```

When I run `grails run-app` and try fetching all data, I still get JSON response with class property. However, when I try to update the source code by deleting some parts, then saving, and then bringing it back to what it was when I run it so that hot code loading is triggered, the exclusion gets applied, and I don't see the class field anymore. What's happening here?

I've set up a XML renderer excluding class field as well but it works right away, without having to rely on hot code loading.

Comment: Did you try grails clean and then again grails run-app ?

Comment: Yes I tried cleaning, and then running the app again, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across [this issue from the official tracker](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10567), from which I got [the answer](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10567?focusedCommentId=77689&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-77689):

> My experience so far is that if I want my RESTful interface to exclude
>   a field from the domain class, I need to configure both of these
>   renders:
>
> ```
> beans = {
>     userRender(JsonRenderer, User) {
>         excludes = ['password']
>     }   
>
>     usersRender(JsonCollectionRenderer, User) {
>         excludes = ['password']
>     } 
> }
> ```